# Measurable function growing at most linearly

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $F$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ which grows at most linearly ($F(x) \leq C|x|$), and is differentiable at zero, $F'(0)=a$. Show that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{nF(x)}{x(1+n^2x^2)}dx=\pi a.$$

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I don't know where to start. I see that outside any neighborhood the integral will tend to zero as n grows, but not sure how to make this rigorous.

Comment: Just an idea: you can use the bound: for $x>0$, $F(x)/x\le C$ and for $x<0$, $F(x)/x\ge -C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only an outline — namely, what I would try to tackle the problem (and may fail).

1. The first idea would be to use the Dominated Convergence theorem, as it is very powerful and would give a nice and immediate argument. However, here it is clear that a straightforward application will not work (to see why, observe that the function $f_n$ to integrate converges pointwise to $0$, and therefore the DCT would not give the right answer).
2. This being said, we need to use the assumption on the derivative at $0$. This is a clear clue that the local behavior at $0$ is important: because of that, trying the change of variable $t = nx$ looks like a natural choice. (As getting $\frac{F(\frac{t}{n})}{\frac{t}{n}}$ gives hope that taking the limit afterwards will result in something like $\frac{F(h)}{h}\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{} F^\prime(0)$.) Indeed (and sweeping at first under the rug the justifications, for the sake of intuition), this would result in looking at the limit of
   $$
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{F(\frac{t}{n})}{\frac{t}{n}}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}
   $$
   which is *very* promising. Indeed, applying the Domiated Convergence Theorem here seems consistent, as the integrand converges pointwise to the function
   $t\mapsto F^\prime(0)\frac{1}{1+t^2} = \frac{a}{1+t^2}$, whose integral happens to be $\pi a$ as desired. (The last point, since $\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{dt}{1+t^2} = \pi$.)

It "only" remains to argue why the change of variable and the application of the DCV after that would be legal.

Comment: beautiful solution